# Terraform state file sharing in Azure Devops

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-devops, terraform-provider-aws

Can someone please help , i have a strange issue , i have 2 pipelines which is associated with 2 different repo , i used first Azure devops pipeline to upgrade the terraform version from 12 to 13(no resource change) and now what i am trying to do is to access the same state file created by pipeline one to add and remove some resources in the same Aws Account . I get 403 error

```
Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.
Error refreshing state: AccessDenied: Access Denied
    status code: 403, request id: 6RH0CW38GPXZZK6Q, host id: zHYzyP9c50QWl+QoTi+7tbaClu2+T6BFrqxDm8xd+mnJOYTd6a3lzVo6tiMJ6Ni91UXvHIQcpjg=
##[error]Error: The process '/usr/bin/bash' failed with exit code 1
```

I have a reason to use 2 different pipelines , my question here cant a same state file be shared between 2 Pipelines ??

When i do a terraform init from my local laptop it is working perfectly fine

Options i tried

1. i tried removing the encrypt true from the backend.tf file (as i am not sure if it uses different kms but both the pipeline is on the same Aws account)
2. Tried removing .terraform and .terraform.lock files (no luck )
3. i changed the statefile and tried running the init , it still failed so that means it is not state file , it is actually not able to access the folders itself from S3 bucket

```
original backend.tf

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    key     = "ad-account/terraform/backend"
    region  = "eu-west-1"
  }
}

changed to 

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    key     = "ad-account/terraform/backend1"
    region  = "eu-west-1"
  }
}

This still failed then changed to 


terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    key     = "ad-account1/terraform/backend"
    region  = "eu-west-1"
  }
}

the above also failed
```

Both pipelines use same AWS credentials and from the same Aws account

Any insight much appreciated please , thanks

Options i tried

i tried removing the encrypt true from the backend.tf file (as i am not sure if it uses different kms but both the pipeline is on the same Aws account)

Tried removing .terraform and .terraform.lock files (no luck )

i changed the statefile and tried running the init , it still failed so that means it is not state file , it is actually not able to access the folders itself from S3 bucket

Comment: How is the bucket permissions configured?

Comment: it says the bucket owner is your aws account

Comment: Is both of your pipelines are connected to AWS environment using same credentials? For Ex: Service connection

Comment: we are using devops templet and both the pipeline is calling the same templet to download credentials

Comment: Thanks for al the comment , the issue is fixed , we use different pools for different stage and for 1st pipeline it is configured correctly and for the second pipeline for acceptance environment it test env agent pool was configured that created a mess out of it , thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for al the comment , the issue is fixed , we use different pools for different stage and for 1st pipeline it is configured correctly and for the second pipeline for acceptance environment test env agent pool was configured that created a mess out of it , thanks guys